# How to calculate month and any additional days between two dates using google sheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want to calculate month between two date and output how month and any additional days by using google sheet

I use this formula to calculate month but i don't know how to calculate any additional days after a complete month.

```
DATEDIF(AG2,TODAY(),"M")
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting this reference of `DATEDIF` (emphasis mine): https://sheetshelp.com/datedif/

> **Syntax**
>
> `=DATEDIF(start_date,end_date,unit)`
>
> `start_date` Date at which to start the calculation
>
> `end_date` Date at which to end the calculation
>
> `unit` Type of output. Choices are “Y”, “M”, “D”, “YM”, “YD”, or “MD”.
>
> ...
>   `"M"` – Number of whole months elapsed between start and end dates
>   `"MD"` – **Number of days elapsed after the number of months shown with the `“M”` or `“YM”` unit.** Can’t go higher than 30.
>   ...